# Adding round corners to only one side of the arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I have been looking into how I can add round corners to an arc and I found out that corners radius is the way to go.The only problem is that I only want to add round corners on only one end of the arc and it seems that cornerRadius was build for adding to both ends.

```
var outerRadius = 50;
var innerRadius =  45;
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                .outerRadius(outerRadius)
                .cornerRadius(outerRadius - innerRadius)
```

Can anyone tell me how I can add round corners to only one side of the arc?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115691/svg-d3-js-rounded-corner-on-one-corner-of-a-rectangle/12124192#12124192) should help -- unfortunately there's no straightforward way to do it as far as I'm aware.