# Round top left corner on a rectangle

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to use js svg library to make a rectangle with only top left corner rounded. I found in it's documentation this example:

```
script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@latest/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var draw = SVG().addTo('#graphix').size(300, 300);
    var rect = draw.rect(300, 300).attr({ fill: '#f06' });
    rect.radius(100);
   
    //rect

  //end
</script>
```

it rounds all of the corners. Is it posible using this library to round only top left or top right corner? Or what should I use as an alterative? I realy can't get it in the previous question that was associated with my post. Solution simply doesn't work. I tried to use some examples from question here [svg / d3.js rounded corner on one corner of a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115691/svg-d3-js-rounded-corner-on-one-corner-of-a-rectangle) but those examples are rounding whole right side instead of doing it only for one corner for example top right/left. The main problem for me is that I have different radius for different corners.

Comment: The duplicate explains how to draw a rectange with one corner rounded. If it "doesn't work" edit your question to show what you're trying and explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry about that. I am trying to make round only of one corner not all side. For example top left for bottom left I have a different radius.

Comment: And that's precisely what that answer I linked you to is about.

Comment: @RobertLongson I just don't t understand how to round those corners by there radius.

Comment: Show what you're doing with the information from the link and describe how it differs from what you want. I.e. post the new code of your attempt.